# Каретка поля ввода в виде подчёркивания

Tags: javascript, html, css

Поле ввода имеет текстовый курсор в виде пульсирующего символа "|". Как бы его изменить, через JS или jQuery, чтобы он отображался в виде пульсирующего символа "_"?

```html
  <input type="text" style="width: 420px" autofocus>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758063/4419684

Comment: непосредственно у инпута этого сделать нельзя. только обходными путями

Answer (score 2):

Задачу можно решить разными способами, ниже представлен один из них:

```js
let dummy = document.querySelector('.dummy');
let input = document.querySelector('input');

function fPosCursor(ev) {
  let val = [...this.value];
  let sel = this.selectionStart;
  val[sel] = `<span class="cursor">${val[sel] || '&ensp;'}</span>`;
  dummy.innerHTML = val.join('');
}

input.addEventListener('mouseup', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('keypress', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('keyup', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('focus', fPosCursor);
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 5px;
  font: 1rem/1em sans-serif;
  background-color: #fa04;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px grey;
}
.wrap:focus-within {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black;
}

.wrap input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
}

.dummy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px; bottom: 0;
  left: 5px; right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrap:focus-within .cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 currentcolor, 0 1px 0 currentcolor;
  animation: cur 0.5s steps(1, end) infinite;
}
@keyframes cur { 50% { box-shadow: none; } }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст">
  <div class="dummy" contenteditable></div>
</div>
```

Плюсы данного подхода:

- Решение простое, с малым количеством кода;
- Отсутствие сторонних библиотек и плагинов;
- Сохранение нативного функционала поля ввода.

Минусы:

- Посредственное быстродействие;
- Сложность масштабирования;
- Проблема отображения, при переполнении поля.

---

Тем не менее, если минусы не критичны, то можно поиграть со стилизацией.

Так как ширина каретки зависит от ширины символа под которым находится, и под "i" или "1" будет плохо видна - моноширинный шрифт будет лучшим выбором:

```js
let dummy = document.querySelector('.dummy');
let input = document.querySelector('input');

function fPosCursor(ev) {
  let val = [...this.value];
  let sel = this.selectionStart;
  val[sel] = `<span class="cursor">${val[sel] || '&ensp;'}</span>`;
  dummy.innerHTML = val.join('');
}

input.addEventListener('mouseup', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('keypress', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('keyup', fPosCursor);
input.addEventListener('focus', fPosCursor);
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 5px;
  font: bold 1rem/1em 'Lucida Console', monospace;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px grey;
}
.wrap:focus-within {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px grey, 0 0 0 2px black;
}

.wrap input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
}
.wrap input::selection {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #0f0a;
}

.dummy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px; bottom: 0;
  left: 5px; right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  color: #0f0;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrap:focus-within .cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 currentcolor, 0 1px 0 currentcolor;
  animation: cur 0.5s steps(1, end) infinite;
}
@keyframes cur { 50% { box-shadow: none; } }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст">
  <div class="dummy" contenteditable></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вспомнил старые добрые времена? Чёрный экран, зелёный яркий шрифт. Смотрится до сих пор классно!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: вспомнил, что есть куча вопросов неотвеченных ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
   cursor: vertical-text;
}
```

Comment: вы изменили курсор, а необходимо изменить caret в самом input

Answer (score 0):

Вид курсора задается в CSS свойством cursor. Таблицу с допустимыми значениями можно посмотреть например тут: https://webref.ru/css/cursor

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос старый, но вдруг кому-то еще актуально. Существуют настройки CSS для текстовых блоков: caret-color, caret-shape. Caret-shape может принимать вид underscore, как раз по теме обсуждения, вот только, кажется, имеет проблемы с работой в разных браузерах.